# Simple SQL Query: need this month data and previous month last 5 days data together

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, dayofweek, days

Need SQL query for this month data and previous month last 5 days data together:

```
SELECT
  CONVERT(VARCHAR (10), wDate, 103) AS wDate,
  Empid,
  Process,
  Model,
  Qty,
  Section,
  Avlbl_Mins,
  NP_Mins,
  L_Mins,
  NP_Reason       AS NPReason,
  Process_Remarks AS PRem,
  Day_Remarks     AS DRem,
  Othermin,
  StdMin,
  Tstdmin,
  TAvlblmin
FROM tblProductionEffcyDetails
WHERE (DAY(EnteredDate) >= DAY(GETDATE()) - 5)
ORDER BY EnteredDate DESC
```

Comment: from where you want to fetch data ???

Comment: Did you try anything

Comment: tried just of 5 days; pls see recent edit

Comment: Are you really using `Mysql`, query syntax belongs to `SQL SERVER`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : to get data from last months last five days

```
WHERE EnteredDate > (DATEADD(DAY,-5,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

For `SQL SERVER 2012+` use this

```
WHERE  EnteredDate >=  dateadd(dd,-4,eomonth(getdate(),-1)) 
  and  EnteredDate < dateadd(dd,1,eomonth(getdate()))
```

For older versions

```
WHERE  EnteredDate >=  dateadd(dd,-5,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)) 
  and EnteredDate < DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, getdate()) + 1, 0))
```

Comment: Iam using SQL SERVER 2012

Comment: @user3926897 - Ofcourse that is the requirement right.. Last 5 days from previous month and current month data